# Async/Await - not understanding why one way is Blocking and another is not

Tags: c#, async-await

Still trying to wrap my head around async/await. I have the following method for drag/drop loading:

```
    private async void p_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

        List<string> CurvesToLoad = new List<string>();
        List<string> TestsToLoad = new List<string>();

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (file.ToUpper().EndsWith(".CCC"))
                CurvesToLoad.Add(file);
            else if (file.ToUpper().EndsWith(".TTT"))
                TestsToLoad.Add(file);
        }

        //SNIPPET IN BELOW SECTION
        foreach (string CurvePath in CurvesToLoad)
        {
            Curve c = new Curve(CurvePath);

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                c.load();
                c.calculate();
            });

            AddCurveControls(c);
        }
        //END SNIPPET

        foreach (string TestPath in TestsToLoad)
        {
            Test t = new Test(TestPath);

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                t.load();
            });

            AddTestControls(t);
        }
    }
```

It is non-blocking as I expected - I am able to navigate between tabs of the TabControl as multiple items are loaded and I can see each tab pop up as it complete loading.

I then tried to convert to this:

```
    private Task<Curve> LoadAndCalculateCurve(string path)
    {
        Curve c = new Curve(path);

        c.load();
        c.calculate();

        return Task.FromResult(c);
    }
```

And then replace the marked snippet from the first code block with:

```
    foreach (string CurvePath in CurvesToLoad)
    {
        Curve c = await LoadAndCalculateCurve(CurvePath);
        AddCurveControls(c);
    }
```

And it becomes blocking - I can't navigate through tabs as it's loading, and then all of the loaded items appear at once when they are completed. Just trying to learn and understand the differences at play here - many thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Updated LoadAndCalculateCurve():

```
    private async Task<Curve> LoadAndCalculateCurve(string path)
    {
        Curve c = new Curve(path);

        await Task.Run(() => {
            c.load();
            c.calculate();
        });

        return c;
    }
```

Comment: You should distinguish two type of tasks - IO bound and CPU bound. Each of them has different nature and should be handled differently.

Comment: `Task.FromResult` returns already completed task so no other threads involved (in general) on that part of code.

Answer (score 2):

Async methods do not execute in a different thread, `await` does not start a thread. `async` merely enables the `await` keyword and `await` waits for something that already runs.

All of that code is running on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

So basically this is what is happening to my knowledge.

In your first code you write

```
    foreach (string CurvePath in CurvesToLoad)
    {
        Curve c = new Curve(CurvePath);

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            c.load();
            c.calculate();
        });

        AddCurveControls(c);
    }
```

this does the async flow as expected  because you are using the Task.Run which adds the work to the ThreadPool queue.

In your second try you don't do this and you are using the same task. Try to use the same logic of (Task.Run) in the second try and I think it will work

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of your `LoadAndCalculateCurve` method is to synchronously create a `Curve`, synchronously load it and perform the calculation, and then return the result wrapped in a `Task`.  Nothing about this is asynchronously.  When you `await` it it will invoke the method, do all of the synchronous work to get the (already completed) task, and then add a continuation to that (already completed) task that will fire immediately.

When you instead use `Task.Run` you're scheduling those long running operations to take place in another thread and *immediately* returning a (not yet completed) `Task` that you can use to run code when it does eventually finish its work.

Comment: Is the only way to schedule a long running operation to take place in another thread by using Task.Run? What would be the ramifications (if any) of having LoadAndCalculateCurve() just return void and calling it within a Task.Run(() => LoadAndCalculateCurve(Curve c))?

Comment: @Worker If it's inherently CPU bound work, that'd be fine.  If it's inherently IO based work, then you should be generating tasks that represent the completion of that work, rather than using `Task.Run`.

Comment: I had changed the LoadAndCalculate method prior to your comment (as shown in question edit) and got the desired result, but as the load() is IO based (calculate() is CPU bound) are you able to provide a short example of how to generate the tasks to represent the completion as opposed to using `Task.Run`

Comment: @Worker It's going to be specific to what the operation actually is.  Typically whatever API you're using to do the IO would provide you with a `Task`, or some other inherently synchronous mechanism that you can create a `Task` out of.